# SSIS file path changing to C:\windows\system32 depending on how I open the project file

Tags: ssis, relative-path

I've been working with SSIS reading different files - from CSVs to XLSXs - with no problems. My paths are relative, so SSIS searches for the files from the project's folder.

Well, today my colleague tried to run a package and he got a curious error message saying that the file could not be found under the "C:\windows\system32" folder. There's no configuration that would point SSIS to that folder and with me and a third colleague it's working well.

After some investigation we discovered that the problem has nothing to do with the user itself, but with how the user opens the project. Since the beginning I've been opening the project by double clicking the ".dtproj" file. My colleague first opens the SSIS development interface then opens the project file from the menu.

Has anyone noticed that behavior? What could be the cause for that?

[error message print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk4TK.png)

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: IDE Standard

Comment: Is it possible they are opening the solution versus the project (and therefore a .user file is/isn't being picked up)?

Comment: That happened! (I can't believe he still uses windows explorer not shoing file extensions) but then we tried again pointing to the right file and the behavior was the same.

Comment: Just repeated the process with my user and that's it. Whenever I open it from the open menu the tasks already show error icons and it cannot find the file on system32 folder. Double clicking the project file works every time.

Of course there's no rush on finding the reason because it is really easy to contour, but we are curious nevertheless.

Comment: Given this, I'd strongly encourage you to provide absolute paths and not rely on the whims of .user files, or whatever mechanism determines this, as you won't have those once you deploy and run in a non-development environment. You can set the path dynamically through a host of methods

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the different ways of launching the IDE end up with different current directories for the IDE process. You can test this by creating a package with only a Script Task, with the one line:

```
MessageBox.Show(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

And then running this project after launching it both ways.

Double-clicking the project or solution file sets the *folder containing that file* as the current directory. (I assume this is standard Windows process launching behaviour when starting a process based on the file extension association.) SSIS packages then look in the *current directory* when the path to the configuration file is relative.

We use relative paths to configuration files all the time to simplify deployment, and have to always remember to open the solutions by double-clicking the SLN file.